# RangeError: Maximum Call Size Exceeding, Stripe session create

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe(both server and client side using sessions) for payments. I'm using node on the backend and react on frontend. I have started building my server route for creating a new session.

Route -

```
router.route('/new-session/:orderId').get(protectMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const order = await Order.findById(req.params.orderId);
        const domain = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}`;

        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
            payment_method_types: ['card'],
            line_items: order.orderItems,
            mode: 'payment',
            success_url: `${domain}/`,
            cancel_url: `${domain}/order/${req.params.orderId}`,
            customer_email: req.user.email,
            client_reference_id: req.params.orderId,
        });

        res.status(200).json({ status: 'success', session });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.send(error.message);
    }
});
```

The error I'm getting is that -

```
[0] RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
[0]     at stringify (/Users/akash/Code/Projects/ProShop/node_modules/qs/lib/stringify.js:47:35)
[0]     at stringify (/Users/akash/Code/Projects/ProShop/node_modules/qs/lib/stringify.js:125:33)
[0]     at stringify (/Users/akash/Code/Projects/ProShop/node_modules/qs/lib/stringify.js:109:33)
[0]     at stringify (/Users/akash/Code/Projects/ProShop/node_modules/qs/lib/stringify.js:125:33)
[0]     at stringify (/Users/akash/Code/Projects/ProShop/node_modules/qs/lib/stringify.js:109:33)
[0]     at stringify (/Users/akash/Code/Projects/ProShop/node_modules/qs/lib/stringify.js:125:33)
[0]     at stringify (/Users/akash/Code/Projects/ProShop/node_modules/qs/lib/stringify.js:109:33)
[0]     at stringify (/Users/akash/Code/Projects/ProShop/node_modules/qs/lib/stringify.js:125:33)
[0]     at stringify (/Users/akash/Code/Projects/ProShop/node_modules/qs/lib/stringify.js:109:33)
[0]     at stringify (/Users/akash/Code/Projects/ProShop/node_modules/qs/lib/stringify.js:125:33)
[0]     at stringify (/Users/akash/Code/Projects/ProShop/node_modules/qs/lib/stringify.js:109:33)
[0]     at stringify (/Users/akash/Code/Projects/ProShop/node_modules/qs/lib/stringify.js:125:33)
[0]     at stringify (/Users/akash/Code/Projects/ProShop/node_modules/qs/lib/stringify.js:109:33)
[0]     at stringify (/Users/akash/Code/Projects/ProShop/node_modules/qs/lib/stringify.js:125:33)
[0]     at stringify (/Users/akash/Code/Projects/ProShop/node_modules/qs/lib/stringify.js:109:33)
[0]     at stringify (/Users/akash/Code/Projects/ProShop/node_modules/qs/lib/stringify.js:125:33)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not directly see where the problem is but can you try to return something from this callback eg:

```
router.route('/new-session/:orderId').get(protectMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const order = await Order.findById(req.params.orderId);
        const domain = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}`;

        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
            payment_method_types: ['card'],
            line_items: order.orderItems,
            mode: 'payment',
            success_url: `${domain}/`,
            cancel_url: `${domain}/order/${req.params.orderId}`,
            customer_email: req.user.email,
            client_reference_id: req.params.orderId,
        });

        return res.status(200).json({ status: 'success', session }); // change here
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.send(error.message); // change here
    }
});
```

Comment: is possible that there is a method that has a loop/recursion happening somewhere we cannot see at the moment. From your error message, I have a feeling that there is method or function called multiple times. i cannot see any form or iteration

Comment: Perhaps, using the process of elimination you could find the problem. maybe in this route just return a success response within empty array and see if you have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to send the whole Session back to the frontend, all you need is the ID and it's the attempt to stringify it that's probably giving you the error.
Instead of

```
res.status(200).json({ status: 'success', session });
```

just do

```
res.status(200).json({ status: 'success', sessionId: session.id });
```

and then on the frontend you parse the JSON and call redirectToCheckout with that `sessionId`.